# How to remove Ljava.lang.String from a combo box in java?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

In the following code, I am trying to access a particular row of database and put it's all element in a combo box but combo box is showing  `[Ljava.lang.String,...` is instead of string value. Please help to show string values in the combo box.

```
 void defaulters()
{
    try 
    {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        final Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ArrayList <String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();           
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT c_name FROM customers" );
        int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String[] row = new String[columnCount];
            for (int i=0; i <columnCount ; i++)
            {
                    row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
            }

            result.add(row);
        }

        final JComboBox cb=new JComboBox();  
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        JLabel  amt= new JLabel("Pending Amount: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        JLabel  cid= new JLabel("Customer ID: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
        final JTextField pamt = new JTextField(10);
        cb.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(result.toArray()));
        JButton sumbit = new JButton("Sumbit");
        f.add(cid);f.add(cb);f.add(amt);f.add(pamt);f.add(sumbit);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setTitle("Defaulters");
        f.setVisible(true);
        String row = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();

         sumbit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
             {
                try {
                    stmt.executeUpdate
                    ("insert into buyers values('"+cb.getSelectedItem()+"','"+pamt.getText()+"');");
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }            
                 System.out.println("Success");
                };
             }); 


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here: `cb.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(result.toArray()));` You call `result.toArray()` which is in turn a `String[][]` array. You see that in your combobox because Java adds the string representation of `String[]`, not the actual contents.

Answer (score 2):

You're storing arrays of Strings (i.e. `String[]` instances) in the combo box model. The `toString()` method of arrays produces what you're seeing.

If you really intend your combo box to contain arrays of strings (which I would not recommend: you'd better use instance of a well-defined class), you need to [set a renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) on the combo box to tell the box how a String array should be renderered.

If you don't intend to have String arrays in your combo box (and you seem to want to have Strings, and not String arrays), then you needs to transform your list of rows into an array of String, instead of an array of String[].

Unrelated: you'd better learn to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), too.